# Limit an integer to certain number of digits and suffix '+'

Tags: java

I am having a problem describing what the following code does. Below is my attempt at its javadoc.

```
/**
 * Convert an integer so that the notion of its size fits within a certain number digits.
 * e.g.
 * Fit 123 to 2 digits -> 99+
 * @param in The integer
 * @param order The order of magnitude to fit it in.
 * @return The 'countified' String.
 */
public static String countify(int in, int order) {
    final int max = (int) Math.pow(10, order);

    if (in >= max) {
        return String.valueOf(max - 1) + "+";
    } else  {
        return String.valueOf(in);
    }
}
```

The idea is simple enough. For any value greater than `10^order` it returns `10^order - 1` plus a `+` (e.g. `123`, with order `2` becomes `99+`), else it returns the number itself. How do I better describe  it? Thanks!

Comment: What you need is a good name for your method right? Because I think the code inside is perfect as is.

Comment: \@TopinFrassi That's what i thought when I posted the question, but clearly I was mistaken :) See @rolfl's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three things I see as being significant issues with your code, and also a suggestion about your method's name.

### Orphaned Else

When you have an if-statement with a guaranteed return in it, there's no need for an else-block. Your code would be better as:

```
if (in >= max) {
    return String.valueOf(max - 1) + "+";
}
return String.valueOf(in);
```

### Input validation

- **bad orders**: your code will produce unexpected results for values with an order outside the range of 1..10. An order of -1 implies a "max" of 0.1, which will become 0, which will mean values like 10 will be presented as `-1+` .... which is hard to fathom.
- **bad values**: Negative input values will cause consternation. An order of 2 implies 2-digits of value, but the input `-12345` will output as `-12345`. Your code does not have a good way of expressing negative input values, so I don't know what to recommend other than avoiding them entirely, and throwing an IllegalArgumentException for negative input.

### Edge Cases

Orders larger than 10 will effectively truncate to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which makes Integer.MAX_VALUE an interesting input..... An order of 10 and an input of Integer.MAX_VALUE, would normally imply an output of `2147483647`, but you respond with `2147483646+`

### Name

The term "clamp" is often used when confronted with this.... where a value is clamped to be within a range, or limit. I would use that as the function name.

### Solution

I would recommend transfroming your internal logic to use long, and be done with it... ;-)

```
public static String clamp(int in, int order) {
    if (order < 0 || in < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Inputs are required to be positive");
    }
    long max = (long)Math.pow(10, order);
    if (max > Integer.MAX_VALUE || in < max) {
        return String.valueOf(in);
    }
    return String.valueOf(max - 1) + "+";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Use less powerful language constructs**

You use `if` and `else`

```
if (in >= max) {
    return String.valueOf(max - 1) + "+";
} else  {
    return String.valueOf(in);
}
```

Using `if` and `else` duplicates `return String.valueOf`

Here the ternary operator comes to the rescue. It looks hard but really is very easy to use.

```
condition ? a : b
```

If `condition` is true, than a, else b. As easy as that.

You can now write `return String.valueOf` just one time:

```
return String.valueOf(in >= max ? (max - 1) + "+" : in)
```

Comment: Appending the `"+"` already results in int to string conversion, so you could (should?) maybe write `return in >= max ? (max - 1) + "+" : String.valueOf(in);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Convert Integer to String if it is exceeding number of digits mentioned in order "it is better to call it width or digits" it will return max +ve number fit in digits mentioned in order concatenating "+" to it.

give more ex. like

- (100, 2) -> "99+"
- (355, 4) -> "355"
- (99, 2) -> "99"

can use method name "toStringWithLimit"

Answer (score 1):

I like @Caridorc's suggestion to use the ternary here.

As for a good name, I think `intToStringWithMaxDigits(int n, int maxDigits)` is clear, if verbose.

Answer (score 0):

#### Math.log10

The answer from [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105419/37033) already covers input validation. I'd like to add that instead of using `Math.pow` with the expected number of digits, you can use `Math.log10` on the argument.